# UILocalNotification Fire date issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am using the UILocalNotification for scheduling alarms for calendar events in my application

I have scheduled an event at 3:30 pm in my application, and set the alert to 1 hour before.

At 2:30, the alert showed up (expected), but it is saying that the event is NOW. On the other hand, native alert is showing that the event is after 1 hour.

**Edit:** Here is, how I schedule the notification:

```
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init]autorelease];

        localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;


        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ \n%@ at: %@",title,todayString,[formatter stringFromDate:Startdate]];
        localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Luanch", nil);

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];

        [dict setObject:ID forKey:@"id"];
        [dict setObject:Startdate forKey:@"start"];
        [dict setObject:endDate forKey:@"end"];
        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:relativeOffset] forKey:@"offset"];
        localNotification.userInfo = dict;
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: Post your code where you create the `UILocalNotification`. Since a `UILocalNotification` will just display what ever you say it to display in the `alertBody` property.

Comment: What i meant in my question is the time displayed to the right of notification title in notification center, the native calendar display how much time still for the event, and my notification display "Now" even though the is not started

Comment: You can't adjust that date. It is always the date that the `UILocalNotification` is fired.

Comment: Is there any way to hide this date label from notification center? i.e "Now"

Comment: No, there is not way to hide this from the notification centre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just native alert is showing the event after specific time, other application show alert with NOW label ,so there is no way to hide NOW label from the notification centre.